# Mail probleme on OPENCART 3.x

Tags: php, html, css, opencart, opencart-3

i use OpenCart for my shop.

But i have migrate on one other hosting.

I try to add my mail for send registration messsage or other.

I have setup corrrectly my smtp but mail not working on SSL / TLS.

Can you help me ?

My error :
`2023-08-09 2:11:45 - PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version in C:\4.5 - SAVE DU 04-29-2021\NewWeb\Tank\market\system\library\mail\smtp.php on line 96
2023-08-09 2:11:45 - PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto in C:\4.5 - SAVE DU 04-29-2021\NewWeb\Tank\market\system\library\mail\smtp.php on line 96.....

I have try SSL and TLS and any work

Comment: It's possible that the SMTP class does not support the TLS version of your mail server. Try using a gmail account to test and see if the email delivers. Alternatively, try PHP mail but that may affect deliverability